# On the surface of the moon

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

On the surface of the moon, acceleration due to gravity is approximately 5.3 feet per second squared. Suppose a baseball is thrown upward from a height of 6 feet with an initial velocity of 15 feet per second.

A) Dertimne the maximum height attained by the baseball.

I have to show all work, relevant calculus, and the appropriate position function.

What I am having trouble with is getting the problem started. Not sure what the position function would be and where I would go from there. I am really struggling in this calculus class and I need detailed help... Help please!

Comment: "Square feet per second" is not a unit of acceleration.

Comment: oops! i don't why i typed it like that, I meant feet per second squared.

Comment: A start, if this is to be done with calculus. Ground: $y=0$; up, positive; $t=0$ when ball is thrown; $y''=-4.3$. You can decide what $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ should be.

Comment: i'm not really following what you're trying to say?

Comment: Can they join rest of the word with MKS? feet? How do they measure Rum? Barrels?

Comment: @Arjang what are you trying to ask?

Comment: @I am trying to ask, please consider joining the rest of the word, use the MKS measurement units, didn't a mars lander crashed because some engineer calculated in feets instead of meters?

Comment: @Arjang the hw problem is in feet, and that is how i have to give my answer, so there is no point in me doing it in meters if my answer has to be in feet, if that is what you mean?

Comment: @Arjang It's called the SI system, and is only relevant in physics. With math we don't care about such earthly matters. We can do one just as well as the other.

Comment: are you able to help me with the problem?

Comment: @cschurman : Others have already given full answer, what more do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’ll measure distance $x$ in feet above the surface of the moon and time $t$ in seconds, with $0$ being the moment at which the ball is released. The ball’s velocity at time $t$ is then $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$, the rate of change of position, and its acceleration is $a(t)=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$, the rate of change of velocity. You’re told that

$$a(t)=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-5.3\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}\;;$$

it’s negative because it’s directed downwards. If you take the antiderivative of a second derivative, you get a first derivative:

$$v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}=-5.3t+C\;.$$

(To avoid visual clutter, I’m omitting the units now.) In order to determine $C$, we must know the actual velocity at some specific moment. Fortunately, we do: at time $t=0$ the velocity is $15$ ft/s. Thus,

$$15=v(0)=-5.3\cdot0+C=C\;;$$

$C=15$, and we now know that $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(t)=-5.3t+15\;.$$

At this point I’ll turn it over to you. You need use this to find a formula for $x(t)$, the height of the ball at time $t$; you can do that in much the way I just got a formula for $v(t)$ from the formula for $a(t)$. Once you have a formula for $x(t)$, use the usual calculus techniques to find its maximum.

Comment: this helps, but i am lost on how to find its maximum....

Comment: @cschurman: Suppose that you were asked to find the maximum of the function $f(x)=x^2-2x-3$ on the interval $[0,3]$; what would you do? Once you have the function $x(t)$, you’ll find that your problem here is very similar to that hypothetical problem.

Comment: could you possibly help me and walk me through this problem in steps, I have fallen behind in class, and I am having a hard time understanding the maximization of a function, and I am not even sure how to maximize your hypothetical function.

Comment: @cschurman: For reasonably nice functions $f$, the maximum and minimum values of $f$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ can only occur at $a$, at $b$, and at points $c\in[a,b]$ where $f\,'(c)=0$, the so-called *critical points*. To find the maximum, therefore, you find $f\,'(x)$, set it to $0$, and solve for the critical points. Then you compute the function values at those points and at $a$ and $b$ and pick out the largest.

Comment: I got this portion of the question figured out, the maximum height the baseball will reach is 33.45. there is more parts to the question, the next part reads "determine how long it takes the ball to hit the surface of the moon" i know i need to use the 2.83 seconds, and the 33.45 feet to find the answer for this part, just not quite sure what i need to do, could you help me with this?

Comment: @cschurman: The $2.83$ is right (to two decimal places), but you should check your formula for $x(t)$: I get a different maximum height. The ball hits the surface of the moon at the moment when $x(t)=0$. Your function $x(t)$ should be a quadratic in $t$, so just set it to $0$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: for the height are you getting a bigger number? so what would the equation i build to get how long it takes the ball to take? also, after this part to the question there are 4 more parts, that i was hoping you could help me out with

Comment: @cschurman: What function did you get for $x(t)$?

Comment: i have the position function of $S(t)=-5.3t^{2}+15t+6$ then i have the velocity function of v(t)=ds/dt= -5.3t+15, and got the 2.83 seconds. and plugged t=2.83 seconds into the position function and got 33.45 feet. I got this stuff from the other answer somebody posted on the question. i'm not really sure what you mean when you are saying x(t) because i don't have a function x(t)

Comment: @cschurman: My $x(t)$ is the height of the ball at time $t$, so it’s what you’re calling $S(t)$, the position function. If you differentiate your position function $S(t)$ with respect to $t$, you **should** get the velocity function $v(t)=-5.3t+15$, but you don’t: $S'(t)=2(-5.3)t+15=-10.6t+15$. How should you change $S(t)$ to fix that?

Comment: would my position function need to be $S(t)=2.3t^{2}+15t+6$

Comment: @cschurman: No; how did you get $2.3$? You’ll have $S(t)=at^2+15t+6$ for some constant $a$. What must $a$ be in order that $S'(t)=-5.3t+15$?

Comment: i'm not really sure what a would need to be? i got 2.3 by taking the square root of -5.3. I'm kind of lost now, what should it be?

Comment: @cschurman: If $S(t)=at^2+15t+6$, what is $S'(t)$?

Comment: $S'(t)=2t+15$ ?

Comment: @cschurman: No, it’s $2at+15$. So what must $a$ be in order for $2at+15$ to be $-5.3t+15$?

Comment: it would have to be -2.65

Comment: @cschurman: There you go! Now use that to recalculate your maximum height. You also have to solve $S(t)=0$, i.e., $-2.65t^2+15t+6=0$ to get the time when the ball hits the moon. (At this point you should probably ask the other parts as a separate question, since the site really doesn’t like these long conversations in the comments.)

Comment: okay i will do that, if i just post a short question with kind of a brief explanation will you follow into it so i don't have to retype a bunch of the question, you have been a HUGE help! thank you so much!

Comment: I got 111.23 feet for my max height?

Comment: @cschurman: You’re welcome! You should make it complete enough that other readers don’t complain; a link to this question would also help. I’ll be around for a bit yet, though I do need to get to bed before **too** awfully long. // That’s **way** to big for the maximum height. You know that it occurs at $t\approx2.83$; $S(2.83)$ is a bit over $27$.

Comment: yea i typed it into the calculator wrong. I posted another question with the other parts in it!

Comment: what would the correct answer for the second part be when i set S(t)=0 ?

Comment: @cschurman: I get a hair over $6$ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is given by $ a(t)=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=-5.3\ $, integrating acceleration function gives us the velocity function

$v(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}=-5.3t+ k\ $

at $ t=0 $    v(t) = $15 f/s $, therefore k= 15 
the velocity function becomes
$v(t)=-5.3t+ 15\ $. 
Integrating the velocity function gives the displacement function 
$s(t)=-5.3t^2+ 15t + k1\ $ at $t=0$, $k1= 6 $. hence 
$s(t)=-5.3t^2+ 15t + 6\ $ 
the maximum height is given when $v(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}=0\ $ 
this is the same as $v(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}=-5.3t+ 15 = 0\ $, this gives $t=2.83 sec $ at maximum height 
substituting is the displacement function, maximum height is: 
$s(2.83)=-5.3(2.83)+ 15(2.83) + 6 = 33.45 feet\ $