# ball on the moon part 3

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

This the final parts to my previous question ( [On the surface of the moon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449257/on-the-surface-of-the-moon) )

The original question reads "On the surface of the moon, acceleration due to gravity is approximately 5.3 feet per second squared. Suppose a baseball is thrown upward from a height of 6 feet with an initial velocity of 15 feet per second.

A)Determine the maximum height attained by the baseball
B)Determine how long it takes the ball to hit the surface of the moon.
C) Find the average velocity of the ball over the time it's in flight
D) Find the moment when the ball's instantaneous velocity is the same as your answer in the previous part.
E) What assurance do we have that there is an answer to part D?

Part A is answered

Comment: With the answer from part (a), are you able to get anywhere? What have you tried?

Comment: @yanbo the answer to part A was 27.39 feet, as far as part B I know I need to set my position function of S(t)=-2.65t^2+15t+6 equal to 0, then I solve for t to get how long it takes for the ball to hit the surface of the moon. That is as far as I have gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(B) You now know that $S(t)=-2.65t^2+15t+6$, where $S(t)$ is the height above the moon’s surface at time $t$. The ball leaves your hand at time $t=0$, and it hits the moon when $S(t)=0$. Thus, all you have to do is solve $S(t)=0$ for $t$.

(C) The ball started at a height of $6$ ft and ended at a height of $0$ ft, so it travelled a net distance of how much? Be careful: this is the **net** distance, and the algebraic sign matters. From (B) you know how long it took. Divide the distance travelled by the time, and of course you get the average velocity $v_{\text{avg}}$.

(D) You know that the velocity at time $t$ is $v(t)=-5.3t+15$, and you know $v_{\text{avg}}$ from (C), so you just have to solve $v(t)=v_{\text{avg}}$ for $t$.

(E) HINT: Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: for part B it would take 3.4 seconds for the ball to reach the surface of the moon, correct?

Comment: so the ball traveled a net distance of -6 feet, so I would take -6 feet and divide that by 3.4 seconds?

Comment: @cschurman: I get a little over $6$ seconds for (B): writing the equation as $2.65t^2-15t-6=0$, we have $$t=\frac{15\pm\sqrt{15^2-4(2.65)(-6)}}{2\cdot2.65}\;.$$ We can ignore the negative solution, so $t\approx6.0355$ unless I made a computational error somewhere.

Comment: so i would rewrite -2.65t^2+15t+6=0 as this-- 2.65t^2-15t-6=0 ?

Comment: @cschurman: Sure: it’s just a matter of multiplying both sides by $-1$, and since $-1\cdot0=0$, the righthand side doesn’t change. Or you can apply the quadratic formula directly to $-2.65t^2+15t+6=0$ and get $$t=\frac{-15\pm\sqrt{15^2-4(-2.65)(6)}}{2(-2.65)}\;;$$ if you do this, you’ll find that you get the same two solutions, but the positive solution will be the one with the **negative** square root. I thought that you might find that a little confusing, so I recommended multiplying through by $-1$ to make the $t^2$ term positive.

Comment: okay yea that makes sense! so now for part C I take -6 feet and divide that by the 6.04 seconds?

Comment: for my $V_{avg}$ I got -.99

Comment: @cschurman: Sounds about right, yes. And that would be in ft/s, since we’ve consistently worked in feet and seconds. At this point (D) should be pretty easy: it’s basically just a little arithmetic.

Comment: so I would go with -5.3t+15=-.99 and then solve that for T

Comment: @cschurman: That’s right.

Comment: t=3.01 seconds. Part E I'm not really sure how to answer that with the mean value theorem, also there is another part, and it has a graph, and the question reads, the graph shows the position function for the baseball. Sketch the lines whose sloes are the average and instantaneous velocities found in parts C and D. (One should be a secant line and the other a tangent line) my question is where do I find the slopes of those lines and how do I know where to place them The graph just looks like a big hill.....

Comment: @cschurman: The graph shows the height $x$ as a function of time $t$: it’s the graph of $x=S(t)$, where the horizontal axis is the $t$-axis and the vertical axis is the $x$-axis. At any value $t_0$ of $t$ the derivative $S'(t_0)$ is the slope of the tangent line to the graph at the point $\langle t_0,S(t_0)\rangle$. But $S'(t_0)$ is also the velocity at time $t_0$: the slope of the tangent line at $t_0$ is the velocity at $t_0$. In (D) you found that this slope is the same as the average velocity when $t\approx3.01$, so it’s at that point on the curve — the point where $t=3.01$ — that you ...

Comment: ... should draw your tangent line. A secant line is a line through two points on a curve. Here we’re interested in the secant line through the points representing the moment when the ball leaves your hand and the moment when it hits the moon. That line starts at the point $\langle 0,6\rangle$ and ends at about $\langle 6.04,0\rangle$. The slope is therefore $$\frac{0-6}{6.04-0}=-\frac6{6.04}\;,$$ and you should recognize that number: you calculated that same ratio to get ... what?

Comment: $V_{avg}$ I got the lines all drawn up, just have to label the graph with the points. I am still a little confused on what I need to write for part D.

Comment: @cschurman: That may be more than we can really work through in this medium without my simply doing it for you, which I don’t want to do. Ignoring some technicalities, the mean value theorem says that if $y=f(x)$ is a reasonably nice function on a closed interval $[a,b]$, there is some point $c\in[a,b]$ where the derivative is equal to $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. But $f\,'(c)$ is the slope of the tangent line at $\langle c,f(c)\rangle$, and $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is the slope of the secant line through the points $\langle a,f(a)\rangle$ and $\langle b,f(b)\rangle$ at the ends of the curve. ...

Comment: Okay, I will just have to think about it a little more. Thank you so much! You were such a great help today, I don't think I would have been able to figure these out without your help! I can't say thanks enough! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: ... What you need to do to finish the problem is see how this relates to what you found in (D) and the lines that you just drew on the graph. You should take a look at the discussion of the mean value theorem in whatever textbook you have available. // You’re welcome!

Comment: From what I can see looking at the graph and what I found, is kind of along the line that there is an answer to part D because the secant line is equal to what I found in part C, and that gives me the slope of the tangent line at the highest point on the graph, which is at t=3.01

Comment: @cschurman: Not at the hightest point: at the highest point the slope is $0$. (That makes sense: remember that the slope is the velocity, and at the highest point the ball is instantaneously at rest, moving neither up nor down.) The value of $t$ where $S'(t)=v_{\text{avg}}$ is a little **past** the point at which the ball reaches maximum height: the average velocity is negative, so the slope at the point in question must be negative, i.e., the ball must be on its way back down.

Comment: Right, I have it written down like that, I caught what I had said after I said it. Again thank you so much! I need to try and catch some shut eye, I'm sure I will have more questions in the next couple weeks my accumulative final is coming up on the 29th!